Subscribe and listen to dynamic number of `tokio::sync::broadcast` channels?
I need to listen to a list of Tokio broadcast channels. Normally, I could just use a select! macro to do this. However, this list of channels can change at runtime.
Two options I've thought of, neither seem ideal

Combine multiple channels into a single stream using the futures::stream::select_all function. But this means if the list of channel change, I have to call futures::stream::select_all again and re-create the single stream. Not sure if this is an expensive operation, I'm guessing it's not cheap.

Spawning a separate Tokio task for each channel I'm subscribed to. Add or drop tasks as my subscription changes. Same concern, because I may have hundreds of channels I need to subscribe to, I'm worried about performance.


Is there a canonical way (or crate) to achieve this? Any advice would be appreciated.

For more context, I have a gRPC server that is establishing bi-direction streams with the clients (in the thousands). I need to do this for each stream/client. That is, each stream needs to subscribe to a dynamically changing list of broadcast channels potentially in the hundreds.

There is https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html which allows pushing new futures after creation. You would call StreamExt::into_future and then reinsert them when they yield a value. And to keep track of which client each one comes from, you can map them from Value to (ClientId, Value).

There's always select_all

tokio_stream::StreamMap was created just for this.

Thanks. This works for me. Would you happen to know if there's any performance penalty for using StreamMap as compared to manually spawning tokio tasks?
